# Ruby: How to write the atrribute values of an object from an array of objects to csv

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, csv

Need to know how to write the atrribute values of an object from an array of objects to csv.

eg.

```
class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :weight, :price
end

def Item.create_item(name, weight, price)
  a = Item.new
  a.name = name
  a.weight = weight
  a.price = price
  return a
end

array_of_items = []

array_of_items << create_item(n1, w1, p1)
array_of_items << create_items(n2,w2,p2)
.....
```

I need to generate a csv file in the following desired output format

row0 - name , weight, price

row1 - n1, w1, p1

row 2 - n2, w2, p2

and  so on

Any directions for the above would be helpful.

EDIT:

Based on the feedback tried the following.

```
class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :weight, :price

  def initialize(name, weight, price)
      @name, @weight, @price = name, weight, price
  end

  def to_s
    [@name, @weight, @price].join(', ')
  end
end

itemlist = []
itemlist << Item.new("Rice", 2, 40)
itemlist << Item.new("Wheat", 3, 80)

CSV.open("items.csv", "wb") do |csv|
 itemlist.each do |i|
  csv << i
 end
end
```

This throws the following error -
    NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for Rice, 2, 40:Item .

If I check itemlist.class, that is Array; itemlist[0].class is Item - No surprises here. I think you  said the to_s instance method defined above is supposed to take care of the printing issue when things are added to the CSV, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as below :

```
require "csv"

class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :weight, :price
end

def Item.create_item(name, weight, price)
  a = Item.new
  [a.name = name,a.weight = weight,a.price = price]
end

CSV.open("/home/kirti/ruby/csv/test.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ['name' , 'weight', 'price']
  csv << Item.create_item(:foo, 23, 11)
end
```

**output:**

```
name,weight,price
foo,23,11
```

Comment: Thanks, the above worked. May I ask what the difference between the create_item method definition that I've used and the one you have used?

Comment: @joetom In your one,you have returned the object of class `Item`,which is not the one,you want to save in your *.csv* file. You want to save the values of the attributes of the object of *Item* class. Thus I wrote `[a.name = name,a.weight = weight,a.price = price]`. Hope it helps. If any more questions you do have please fire me..

Answer (score 0):

A ruby method always return the last value. Your method Item.create_item return a.price, since that is the last value.

To solve the problem you have two options.

Add an explicit return statement:

```
def Item.create_item(name, weight, price)
  a = Item.new
  a.name = name
  a.weight = weight
  a.price = price
  return [name, weight, price]
end
```

Use something called Parallel Assignment

```
def Item.create_item(name, weight, price)
  a = Item.new
  a.name, a.weight, a.price  = name, weight, price
end
```

The second option will also return an array with the values you want as it is the last line of the method.

Babai's answer tells you how to output the values to a csv.

Edit:

In your code when you return the item a it does not know how to print this out when adding it to the csv. The way to solve it is to define the to_s method, a method called when things are added to csvs or printed to screen.

Notice that I also rewrote the function a both to use instance variables and the initialize function. Hope it does not add too much confusion.

```
class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :weight, :price

  def initialize(name, weight, price)
      @name, @weight, @price = name, weight, price
  end

  def to_s
    [@name, @weight, @price].join(', ')
  end

end

array_of_items = []
array_of_items << Item.new('name_of_item', 'weight_of_item', 'price_of_item')
```

edit after comment:

after looking at the docs for the CSV module, the CSV wants an array. There are two ways to do it.

either:

```
CSV.open("items.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  itemlist.each do |item|
    csv << [item.name, item.weight, item.price] 
    # item.name works because we added the attr_accessor
  end
end
```

or:

```
class Item
  def to_array
    [@name, @weight, @price] 
  end
end

CSV.open("items.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  itemlist.each do |i|
    csv << i.to_array 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the problem if the create_item method returns Item object as in "return a" . On trying this and subsequently calling "csv << a" ruby throws an error saying that map method is not defined to Item sorts.

Comment: Well, first off the way you create the Item is a bit strange. I added a thing to my answer to clarify how one normally would write the code.

Comment: I tried the normal method via instance variables et al. But it throws an error while adding the Item to the array- `NoMethodError: undefined method 'map' for Rice, 2, 40:Item` . I see you've mentioned that the to_s method defined should've taken care of the printing part, but that doesn't seem to be working. Please see the EDIT in the original post.

Comment: Ahh, the csv really want an array, so we must create a to_array function. See my edit to this answer.